# How to select top 10 most sold items for every country sorted by name of country and quantity

Tags: mysql, sql

HERE IS WHAT I TRIED BUT IT DOESNT SEEM TO WORK:

```
select * from item as i
        inner join items_receipts as ir on i.id=ir.item_id
        inner join receipt as r on ir.receipt_id=r.id
        inner join country as c on r.country_id=c.id
        group by c.id
        order by count(r.id)
        limit 10
```

HERE IS EER DIAGRAM:
[image]

Comment: You need to group the count by country using ```GROUP BY``` and then order it in a descending order before you limit to 10.

Comment: How to group count by country using group by??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
select count(r.id),i.name,c.name as catname from item as i
        inner join items_receipts as ir on i.id=ir.item_id
        inner join receipt as r on ir.receipt_id=r.id
        inner join country as c on r.country_id=c.id
        group by i.id,c.name
        order by count(r.id) desc,c.name desc
        limit 10
```